# How do i pass an object from codebehind to populate a JQuery UI control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

So I am new to using jquery and asp.net webforms together. The idea is that i will have a repeater, on a webform page, populated by data from a database. Now i want this repeater to have an edit button which will open a jquery ui dialog with textboxes, and the data from the repeater should populate the jquery ui dialog controls. How do i send data back and forth from both ends. Any sample code will be much appreciated.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I have a rough plan , to achieve this.

1. Use repeater to show data , lets  say you have firstname, userid (assumption: this is the primary key) etc. Add a button called `edit` in repeater template.
2. Write a JS say (EditUser), and attach that js function to `edit` button. And pass the `firstname` and `userid` to `EditUser` JS function.
3. Have a hidden field, to store `userid` that is passed to `EditUser`.
4. `EditUser` will bring jQuery dialog, also it will  show the firstname in textbox as editable field.
5. Write a `WebMethod` , use `ajax` to post `userid` stored in hidden field and newly modified `firstname` to `webmethod`.

Webmethod - Server code written in code behind, can be callable via `ajax`. Help - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

6. In webmethod, write code to take `userid` and changed value, save to DB.
7. On ajax callback, actually update that value in repeater ( you need some jquery selector logic to fetch that control and set value).

Comment: Hi Ari, this approach will work if there is only one "user" which i can easily get the id from an hidden field, what if i have a table/repeater with a name,  is the first td.. and a button in the 2nd td.. how will i get the button to match the right name, even if i used a hidden field, assuming their will be many more rows.. how will i get the button to point to the right datarow

Comment: @ifelabolz , particularly for the case you said, you have to use proper jquery selector to get value. If you can update your question with html markup, I can suggest you required selector to get hidden field.